# Adding column from the content type Video (length) to a library to display length of videos

Tags: content-type, video

I would like to use the column belonging to the content type "video". When I use an asset library and upload mp4 short videos the column remains empty. Is there something I need to do or Microsoft simply stopped making those columns/content types work?

Comment: Are you using the modern experience?

Comment: yes, I have done the same thing a couple of years ago on modern and it worked, I also added a calculated column to turn seconds into hours

Comment: have added an answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

This content type is used in conjunction with the SharePoint classic experience. I believe this is because there are a number of classic application pages that are used to process the video file and fill out a number of columns in the Video content type. You will need to enable the Video and Rich Media (Classic) site collection feature to use this functionality. However, I would recommend that you use Stream v2 for video content instead.

As confirmed by Marc Mroz (product owner for Microsoft's Office Media group), the Video set content type is not being used going forward.

[image]

[marc on X: "@sympmarc YES! Just inherit from the normal Document CT! We aren't adding a new CT for Stream on SharePoint, everything we are adding works just from the normal document CT. The old "Video set" stuff is NOT being used going forward." / X](https://twitter.com/MarcMroz/status/1534621124306251776?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1534621124306251776%7Ctwgr%5E2c8bb39a8e0c8f22eebe55981f974999ef1984b4%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsympmarc.com%2F2022%2F09%2F27%2Fcreating-custom-content-types-for-stream-in-sharepoint%2F)

Similarly confirmed by other Microsoft MVPs:

[Creating Custom Content Types for Stream in SharePoint](https://sympmarc.com/2022/09/27/creating-custom-content-types-for-stream-in-sharepoint/)

With regards to the modern experience, I would recommend using the Stream v2 (built on SharePoint). It seems the new version of Stream stores the files using the document content type.

Comment: sorry to disagree but I have a classic site, turned the library into classic view, used the asset library and after uploading the length still does not show. I also remember that when I have done it a couple of years ago, I had used the modern view.

Comment: Not only that. In the "all assets" view (the one without thumbnails) I also extracted the "file size" and that one as well is empty!

Comment: This is a classic content type/feature, I imagine it's not supported in modern. Even if it worked for a bit, it's not guaranteed. If Microsoft themselves are not using the video content type, this is a good reason to use Stream v2 or to emulate however Stream is storing the files.

Comment: Have updated my answer, there is a feature that you would need enabled for that classic content type. I wouldn't recommend using this legacy functionality though.

Comment: The feature has been enabled from the moment I attempted this. If it is not enabled you are not even able to have the video content type. I do not need recommendations about Stream as it is not giving the information I want to see. I was looking for strong technical expertise on the obvious changes in the content type department and why it is not even showing file size but I am not getting it.

Comment: Since you aren't happy with my technical expertise, I have copied in the advice of Microsoft's own product managers and another Microsoft MVP. Their advice mirrors mine. Personally, I don't build solutions around legacy features so admittedly, I had forgotten some details of this content type.